# Inverse Incomplete Gamma Functions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, numerical-computing

I have a problem which is posed in terms of incomplete Gamma functions and inverse incomplete Gamma functions.  Recall that where a Gamma function is a particular integral from 0 to infinity, incomplete gamma functions add another parameter, x, and integrate from 0 to x (a lower incomplete) and from x to infinity (an upper incomplete.)

I know Matlab has functions covering all those functions:  complete Gamma functions, upper and lower incomplete Gamma functions, and the inverses.  However, Matlab implements their incomplete Gamma functions as **regularized** incomplete gamma functions, which is to say, they are divided by the complete Gamma functions.

I am looking for Matlab implementations of the **non-regularized** incomplete Gamma functions, most especially the **inverse incomplete** Gamma functions.  Does anyone know of such a thing, or an easy way to construct one?  (The 'forward' incomplete Gamma functions are easy to implement by scaling, but there may be faster implementations.  If there is a simple implementation of the inverses, it eludes me.)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you formulated your problem in terms of the regularized gammas? There are good reasons these functions (and others) are implemented as normalized/regularized...

Comment: It's not my formulation, unfortunately.  It is possible that the paper *means* regularized Gamma functions and is just badly written; one reason I'm looking for the non-regularized version is to do it both ways and compare against the original paper.  (Gamma functions are outside my expertise-- I'd love to hear why the regularized functions are used, if it is an easy thing to fit in a comment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the R2014a release, MATLAB incorporates the function *igamma*, which does what you where looking (back then in 2012...):

> I am looking for Matlab implementations of the non-regularized
>   incomplete Gamma functions, most especially the inverse incomplete
>   Gamma functions.

Just so that everybody knows.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to interface to C/C++, the GSL (GNU Scientific Library) has implementations of both the normalized and unnormalized incomplete Gamma functions, such as gsl_sf_gamma_inc.

Or run the GSL versions in C as a quick check on your Matlab results.